# Accessing an array in emu8086

Tags: arrays, assembly, element, x86-16, emu8086

Can someone please tell me the most effective way to access an array's element in emu8086?
As an example I got this array:

```
tab db 30h,35h,32h,37h,38h,39h,31h
```

Is it wrong to write `mov si, offset tab` and then access to the element using `si`? Like `tab[si]`, `tab[si+1]`, `tab[si+n]`, etc.
Am I obliged to keep using `lodsb`/`lodsw`?

Comment: Arrays are just a convenient abstraction. All you really have are consecutive memory addresses. The machine doesn't care how you refer to them, though human readers of your code might.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it wrong to write `mov si, offset tab` and then access to the element using si? like `tab[si]`, `tab[si+1]`, `tab[si+n]`... etcetera.

That would be very wrong indeed! Assuming emu8086 can accept `tab[si]` where (part of) the displacement component lies outside of the square brackets, you would erroneously be adding the offset to the array **twice**. Once in the initialization of SI (`mov si, offset tab`), and once more in the load/store instruction that uses the addressing mode `tab[si]`.

Four ways to solve it:

- Setup SI with `mov si, offset tab` and access the first element with `[si]` and the second element with `[si+1]`.
- Setup SI with `xor si, si` (same as `mov si, 0`) and access the first element with `tab[si]` and the second element with `tab[si+1]`.
- Setup SI with `mov si, offset tab` and access all of the
  elements with `[si]` because in between accesses you will have incremented the SI register as part of a loop's logic.
- Setup SI with `xor si, si` (same as `mov si, 0`) and access all of the
  elements with `tab[si]` because in between accesses you will have incremented the SI register as part of a loop's logic.

> Am I obliged to keep always using `lodsb`/`lodsw`?

Definitely no. But should you ever need to write the *most compact* solution, then often the use of these string primitives will do the job.